# How to Click on iPad pair Trust Popup?

Tags: ios, appium

```
idevicepair pair
```

I am entering the above command in the Terminal and Trust popup Displays  on iPad is there any way to perform click action on `Trust` automatically either than manually clicking on trust

[image]

Comment: I don't think so. That would be a security vulnerability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no way** to perform tap action programmatically.